# How to prove polynomial has repeated roots?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> if we have a increasing function, say  $f(x)$,  so we can say $f'(x) \geq 0,\space \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> We take a special case: if $f'(x)=0$ has a root $\alpha$ and $f(\alpha)=0$ this would mean $f(x)=0$ has repeated root

Can anyone please prove the second statement.

Comment: maybe you could write $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some function $g(x)$, use that $f'(x)=(x-a)g'(x)+g(x)$ and the hypothesis $f'(\alpha)=0$ to obtain that $g(x)=(x-\alpha)h(x)$ for some $h(x)$ and conclude from here.

Comment: If $ f $ is an arbitrary function, the meaning of "repeated root" is not very obvious. For example, $f(x) = x^{4/3}$ has $f'(0) = 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, so would we call $0$ a repeated root of $ f $? If so, what is its multiplicity?

Comment: The second statement is not a theorem, it is a definition: this is how you define a double root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the roots of $f(x)$ be $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$. Then,
$$f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$$
$$f'(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_3)\cdots(x-a_n)+(x-a_2)(x-a_3)\cdots(x-a_n)+\cdots$$
Let $a_1$ be a root of $f'(x)$. 
But $$f'(a_1)=(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)\cdots(a_1-a_n)=0$$
Thus, one of the factors must be zero. Let the factor $(a_1-a_j)=0$ for some $2\le j\le n$. Then, $a_1=a_j$, and we have that $a_1$ is a repeated root.

Comment: But I think that $f$ is not necessarily a polynomial.

Comment: @ramsay Must $f$ be a polynomial? I seem to have missed that. Else, the answer would need to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can *Taylor's formula*, which is an exact formula for polynomials: suppose $f$ has degree $n$. Then 
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f(\alpha)+ f'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)+f''(\alpha)\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2!}+\dots +f^{(n)}(\alpha)\frac{(x-\alpha)^n}{n!}\\
&=(x-\alpha)^2\Biggl[f''(\alpha)\frac1{2!}+\dots +f^{(n)}(\alpha)\frac{(x-\alpha)^{n-2}}{n!}\Biggr].
\end{align*}

Comment: I am seeing this formula first time can you say what does $\alpha$ represent here.

Comment: The root, and he is expanding the function in a part of a Taylor series around this point, look up Taylor's theorem on Wikipedia.

Comment: Well, here it's the name of the root in your post. In a general situation, it's any real number since a polynomial has domain $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @B. Pasternak: not a Taylor series, a Taylor polynomial. That's the main point.